# How to Upload Thousands of products with MAGMI with different options

Tags: magento, upload, product, magmi

I am new to magento. I have been running my store and getting more sales then I ever did since I switched to Magento. Something I haven't been able to figure out yet is setting options for my products. Here is where I am currently at.

My distributor provides me a list of products (over 19,000) I open it in Macro and run a custom script where it then is configured to be able to upload to my website using MAGMI.  This works great. But the issue I have is MANY of the products (not all) come in different sizes or different options. I sell pet products. SO there may be one cage that is 22 inches but also comes in 36 inches, 46 inchs, etc. Dog food 5lbs, 15lbs, 36 lbs. ETC. I currently have them listed all by their self as a simple product. I would like my website to be easier to navigate for my customers to find the products they are looking for. Is there a way I can set products to upload and have these kind of options. Everything has their own UPC which I use as the SKU for uploading to magento. Again, I am working for thousands of products so I am looking for the easiest solution.

Please sure your experience or ideas.

Answer (score 0):

It's more a magento attribute configuration issue than a magmi issue.
For all those "variable" options, set their attributes as "dropdown" type and magmi will automagically fill the values.

And since dropdowns attributes can be configured automatically to be used as layered navigation in magento , you'll reach your goal.

I think you should carefully design your product model & attribute sets to distinguish finely between the different types of products you sell.

Magmi will adapt automatically imported values to target attribute characteristics.

However,in magento you cannot directly change an attribute type, you'll surely need to destroy/recreate attributes in backend.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Would you be able to provide me with a CSV format so I can see how this would be upload in MAGMI and what would need to be set in magento admin… Need a little more clarifying thank you again for the response!

Comment: magmi format should not change from what you already use (attribute codes as column names). the only change to perform is how each attribute you want to use as option is defined in magento. i suppose you did set all as textfield while you need to define them as "dropdown" in Catalog/manage attributes menu.

Comment: but how can hundreds of different attributes be assigned to thousands of products easily?

Comment: especially if the other products/attrinnbutes are included in the file that is uploaded.

Comment: the attributes themselves (the columns) need to exist. but their values are automatically created/reused on the fly from their text values as dropdown options while magmi reads the file.